# using ng-hide animations to create a simple slide-show kind of effect

Tags: angularjs

In my application I am attempting to create a slide-show like effect.

i.e first show a certain text.. then hide is (animatedly) ..then show another piece of text... then hide it.. and so on..

Kind of like slide show.

Following the example from AngularJS lessons:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/DCvvNxnitHpcAowKKSvI?p=info
```

I have set my css as below:'

```
.part1 {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 200px;
}

.part1.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.part1.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in 2s;
  transition: opacity ease-in 2s;
}

.part1.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.part2 {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
    height: 200px;
}


.part2.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.part2.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.5s;
  transition: opacity linear 0.5s;
}

.part2.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

However, there is no animation happening between part1 and part2.

A plnkr is here:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/hrxtvxIIAysEw1iF2DLn?p=info
```

Is there some other class that I need to add ?

Comment: You aren't including ng-animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ng-animate

http://plnkr.co/edit/AwEToSEnSYiZePF5KhO9?p=preview

you have to add the cdn and inject into app like so

```
['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']
```

Not 100% sure what effect you want with your css, but i'm guessing you will have to tweak a little bit, but this will get the angular animate part working for you.